# Cache hit or miss rate in AIX

Tags: multithreading, aix

Is there any command to find out how my AIX box is doing in terms of Cache hit/miss. I am using IBM Power 7 system. OS is AIX 6.1. I want to check if the SMT value [set to 4] is optimum.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, I am not 100% sure but I'm fairly sure that there is not a method of monitoring cache hits / misses.  I've never heard of such a critter.

Usually folks test on SMT 1, 2, and 4 and see what works best for them.  Its more complicated than one value can indicate.  Also, in general, before the application is tuned, SMT 2 tends to yield the best results.

I would suggest surfing around and finding reading materials.  AIX has "Redbooks" and "Red Papers" and I know they have a few on performance tuning.

Comment: I am not getting a meaningful way to calculate it. However IBM must be having a way to get it calculated. Let me try searching more.